# Sitecore Eviblog Module

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

We are using Sitecore Version 6.4.1. We are planing to use Eviblog module for our blogs. We already have a blog running on BlogEngine .net.

Is there any way to get all existing blogs into new Eviblog module? Or do we have any other blog module with Sitecore which can do same.

Comment: you could check with the Sitecore Developer Network and see if someone has created a migration tool http://sdn.sitecore.net It's been a couple years since I logged in there, I cannot remember my username or password at the moment, to check if they have a solution or not

Answer (score 1):

There's a new version of EviBlog called [WeBlog](http://trac.sitecore.net/WeBlog). It supports migrations from WordPress. If you can migrate from BlogEngine.NET to WordPress, you can then migrate to WeBlog. See "[How to Import Wordpress Content](http://trac.sitecore.net/WeBlog/wiki/WordpressImport)"